# Поиск в БД MySql по JSON

Tags: php, laravel5, october

Подскажите, есть ли какие-либо штатные средства в October CMS или Laravel, которые позволяют производить поиск в базе данных, если поле в json формате и юникоде (кириллица)?
Пример записи в поле "content":
[{"stage":"\u041f\u043e\u0441\u0442\u0440\u043e\u0435\u043d\u0438\u0435 \u0441\u0438\u0441\u0442\u0435\u043c\u043d\u043e\u0439 \u043c\u043e\u0434\u0435\u043b\u0438","text":"\u041c\u043e\u0434\u0435\u043b\u044c"}]

Сейчас ищу так (это не учитывая указанное выше поле):

```html
<?php
  $result = Workflow::query()
              ->where(function ($query) use ($request) {
                  return $query
                      ->where('title','like','%'.$request.'%');
              })
              ->get();
?>
```

Нужно сделать что-то вроде этого:

```html
<?php
      $result = Workflow::query()
                  ->where(function ($query) use ($request) {
                      return $query
                          ->where('title','like','%'.$request.'%')
                          ->orWhere('content','like','%'.$request.'%');
                  })
                  ->get();
    ?>
```

Где поле "content" это данные в формате json.

Спасибо.

P. S. Поиск не должен сильно нагружать сервер.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну, можно привести к такому же виду значение поиска. Хотя на самом деле есть "более другое" решение - хранение JSON непосредственно в [поле типа JSON](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json.html) (MySQL v.5.7+). Думаю, другие СУБД также поддерживают этот формат, поскольку он весьма распространен. Тогда и поиск попроще будет, и штатными средствами любой CMS.

Comment: @Igor_Dyshlenko, спасибо за быстрый ответ. Забыл упомянуть, MySql версии 5.6. Сейчас вижу только способ кодирования поискового запроса в нужный формат, но это будет происходить долго.

Comment: Отапгрейдиться на 5.7 или 8 никак?

Comment: К сожалению, нет возможности.

Comment: Сочувствую. Тоже иногда приходится... PHP 5.4 версии придерживаться...